# PhantomsJS rejects cookies set programmatically

Tags: webdriver, phantomjs

I tried to set a cookie programmatically and PhantomJSDriver rejects that cookie even if cookie belongs to the current domain. The error message is very generic not revealing much details:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.UnableToSetCookieException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to set Cookie",...

Same command works with FirefoxDriver and ChromeDriver (see test cases to reproduce below).

1. Is there some workaround or fix for that?
2. How can I troubleshoot the problem better, e.g., get more informations about rejection reason from PhantomJS?

I'm using PhantomJSDirver 1.2.1 with phantomjs 2.2.1

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.startsWith;

public class CookiesTest {


    @Test(dataProvider = "webDrivers")
    public void shouldAcceptCookieForCurrentDomain(String type, Supplier<WebDriver> drivers) {
        WebDriver driver = drivers.get();

        driver.get("http://www.bbc.com");
        assertThat(driver.getCurrentUrl(), startsWith("http://www.bbc.com"));
        driver.manage().addCookie(
                new Cookie.Builder("MYCOOKIE", "value").domain("www.bbc.com").build());
        assertThat(driver.manage().getCookieNamed("MYCOOKIE").getValue(), equalTo("value"));

        driver.close();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "webDrivers", expectedExceptions = InvalidCookieDomainException.class)
    public void shouldRejectedCookieForDifferentDomain(String type, Supplier<WebDriver> drivers) {
        WebDriver driver = drivers.get();

        driver.get("http://www.bbc.com");
        assertThat(driver.getCurrentUrl(), startsWith("http://www.bbc.com"));
        driver.manage().addCookie(
                new Cookie.Builder("MYCOOKIE", "value").domain("different.domain.com").build());

        driver.close();
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] webDrivers() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/mgawinec/dev-tools/chromedriver/chromedriver");

        Supplier<WebDriver> phantomJSDrivers = () -> new PhantomJSDriver();
        Supplier<WebDriver> firefoxDrivers = () -> new FirefoxDriver();
        Supplier<WebDriver> chromeDrivers = () -> new ChromeDriver();
        return new Object[][]{
                {"phantomJS", phantomJSDrivers},
                {"firefox", firefoxDrivers},
                {"chrome", chromeDrivers}};
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest development version of PhantomJS (2.2.0-development) contains a fix for this problem.

Since PhantomJS releases are oncea year and I couldn't wait that much time I downloaded their sources and compiled them (they do not provide daily builds, aka snapshots).

Release of PhantomJS 2.2: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13937

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem, and I got it to work by adding the cookies with javascript.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
js.executeScript("document.cookie = \"cookieName=cookieValue;path=/;domain=www.bbc.com\"");
```

I am running PhantomJS version 2.1.1